# Illustrator Size issue : Avery® Print-to-the-Edge Oval Labels

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, logo

I am new in logo designing. And I am told by my boss to design a logo which will be used as posters.

He told me that the size should be : `Avery® Print-to-the-Edge Oval Labels`

And I have no idea what it is and how to get that in illustrator.
I tried to get information on net but could not find anything helpful.

It will be of great help if the stack exchange community helps.

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE. Did you try google? I can find templates at 4 clicks. https://www.google.com/search?q=Avery%C2%AE+Print-to-the-Edge+Oval+Labels+illustrator+tenplate&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=Avery%C2%AE+Print-to-the-Edge+Oval+Labels+illustrator+template

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I went through this link http://www.avery.com/avery/en_us/Templates-%26-Software/Templates/Marketing-Solutions/Oval-Labels-8-per-sheet-Adobe-Illustrator_Adobe-Illustrator.htm?N=4294967207%204294965742%204294963030&refchannel=3980ac83ae70a110VgnVCM1000002118140aRCRD And I used this template. It gives me 8 oval shapes in a page. Can you tell me what is the use of it when I will be designing the logo?

Comment: Its the shapes of the stickers you are presumed to make. So i suppose he wants a oval logo that will work as a sticker. The shape should be the same for the differently sized lablels.

Comment: @joojaa But in the template there are 8 oval shapes as seen in the link. So am I supposed to draw the logo inside the oval shape..and then there will be 8 oval logo in the artboard..which is quite confusing?

Comment: Your boss probably means that he wants that kind of ratio, the same as one label. Ignore the 8 labels; as Joojaa said, it's probably only to give you an idea of the kind of shape the logo should have or that it should fit on one sticker perfectly. In doubt, you should really ask your boss. It's not a common way to ask for a logo and we can only assume he wants a similar width x height ratio. And just so you know, logos in Illustrator can be resized at any size without loss of quality if you only use vector.